# Python Pandas: Json to Excel just one row exports issue

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a issue with Python Pandas. My code is showing first element but not showing another. How can I solve this issue? I shared a screenshot. My code added just Admin parent, HAKAN MISIRLI child.

My Json:

```html
{
  "ADMİN" : {
    "HAKAN MISIRLI" : [ 33333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
  },
  "AKPINAR GES" : {
    "BAHRİ KAŞARCI" : [ 44444444444, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
  },
  "Gölbaşı Ges" : {
    "MOLLA AHMET ŞAHİN " : [ 555555555555, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
  }
}
```

My code:

```html
url = "the url of my Json file "

    with urllib.request.urlopen(url + ".json") as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
        role = list(data.keys())[0]
        name = list(data[role].keys())[0]
        listson = data[role][name]
        columns = ["Saha", "İsim", "TC Kimlik"] + list(range(1, len(listson)))
        rows = ["Personel"]
        dfson1 = pd.DataFrame([role, name] + listson).T
        dfson1.columns = columns
        dfson1.index = rows

    dfson1.to_excel("export.xlsx")
```

Export from this code:
[screenshot from my code export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiKcZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like you looped over the json as it's not in a list. Here's an alternative to consider. You can go line by line to see what the code is doing.

Try:

```
data = '''{
  "ADMİN" : {
    "HAKAN MISIRLI" : [ 33333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
  },
  "AKPINAR GES" : {
    "BAHRİ KAŞARCI" : [ 44444444444, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
  },
  "Gölbaşı Ges" : {
    "MOLLA AHMET ŞAHİN " : [ 555555555555, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
  }
}'''

dataj = json.loads(data)
df = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(j) for j in [dataj]]) 
df1 = df.T.reset_index()
df1[["Saha", "İsim"]] = df1['index'].str.split('.', expand=True)
dft = pd.DataFrame(df1[0].tolist())
df_final = pd.concat([df1[["Saha", "İsim"]], dft], axis=1)
df_final.rename(columns={0:'TC Kimlik'}, inplace=True)
```

Ouput

```
          Saha                İsim     TC Kimlik  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31
0        ADMİN       HAKAN MISIRLI   33333333333  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1  AKPINAR GES       BAHRİ KAŞARCI   44444444444  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2  Gölbaşı Ges  MOLLA AHMET ŞAHİN   555555555555  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```